# Including headers from /usr/local/include and libraries from /usr/local/lib

Tags: c++

I have just installed GLFW on OS X 10.9. The headers were installed to `/usr/local/include` and the library was installed in `/usr/local/lib`.

I am wondering what else I would have to do to get my C++ program to include the headers like `#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"` rather than specifying the whole path like `#include "usr/local/include/GLFW/glfw3.h"`.

Same thing goes for the library because as of now I can't even link the library using `-lglfw3`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Operating system? Mac, Linux?...

Comment: @GermánDiago OS X 10.9

Comment: @GuntherFox It doesn't make a difference when I use either one. It still can't find the specified header.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would pass `-I /usr/local/include` to the compiler as preprocessor flag, and `-L /usr/local/lib` to the compiler as linker flag. So to build a single source application `small.cc` compile it as

```
  g++ -Wall -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib \
      small.cc -o small -lglfw3
```

If building with `make` just have

```
  CXXFLAGS += -I/usr/local/include
  LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib
```

in your `Makefile`

If using shared libraries, add once `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `ldconfig` (at least on Linux).