# Why is fmt library not found after installing fmt and gcc compiler with brew?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, homebrew, fmt

I am using MACOS Mojave version 10.14.3 and need to use GNU compiler and not clang.

I installed gcc compiler using `brew install gcc`.
Then I installed fmt library using `brew install fmt`.

I put `#include <fmt/format.h>` at the top of my C++ script

Then I type:

```
/usr/local/bin/g++-8 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++17 -MMD -MP -MF"src/trail2.d" -MT"src/trail2.o" -o "src/trail2.o" "../src/trail2.cpp"
```

However I get this error:

```
fatal error: fmt/format.h: No such file or directory
```

Same happens when I try using the boost library.

When I use clang, fmt and boost are found without problem.

Just in case I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers. Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0).

To be specific, how can I get fmt library to work with the gcc I installed with brew?

What I have in my Mac at /usr/local/Cellar is:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 aaa  staff    96 Feb 22 22:07 gcc
drwxr-xr-x   3 aaa  staff    96 Feb 23 01:58 fmt
```

What I have in my Mac at /usr/local/Cellar is:

```
    lrwxr-xr-x    1 aaa  admin        29 Feb 22 22:07 c++-8 -> ../Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/c++-8
    lrwxr-xr-x    1 aaa  admin        29 Feb 22 22:07 cpp-8 -> ../Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/cpp-8
    lrwxr-xr-x    1 aaa  admin        29 Feb 22 22:07 g++-8 -> ../Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/g++-8
    lrwxr-xr-x    1 aaa  admin        29 Feb 22 22:07 gcc-8 -> ../Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/gcc-8
```

Thanks for the help in advanced

Comment: This is not an issue with GCC, it's an issue where the *library* is installed. If it's not installed in a "standard" location, you must tell the `g++` frontend program where to find the header and library files. Use the `-I` (upper-case i) option to specify where the header files are installed, and the `-L` and `-l` (lower-case L) options for any linker libraries.

Comment: I'd guess that's [/usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25540848/243245)

Comment: Considering the contents of `/usr/local/Cellar` my *guess* is that you need to add `-I/usr/local/Cellar`. Since I don't know how `brew` organizes its packages when installed, perhaps something like `-I/usr/local/Cellar/fmt/include`? You can add the directory in your Eclipse project settings somewhere (Preprocessor settings tab or similar?), but then usually without the actual `-I` option.

Comment: Hi. I am new user in C++. Could you please help me with how my g++ command line should look like?
In `/usr/local/lib` I have this: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 aaa  admin  32 Feb 23 01:58 libfmt.a -> ../Cellar/fmt/5.3.0/lib/libfmt.a`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way **homebrew** works is that it puts everything in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/PACKAGE-NAME/PACKAGE-VERSION
```

and then it creates links to those things for binaries in `/usr/local/bin`, e.g.

```
/usr/local/bin/grep -> /usr/local/Cellar/grep/4.17/bin/grep
```

so that you just need to put `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH and all **homebrew** programs will be runnable by name, e.g. `grep` in the above example.

---

It does the same thing for compiling, it puts the actual headers and libraries in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/PACKAGE-NAME/PACKAGE-VERSION/include
/usr/local/Cellar/PACKAGE-NAME/PACKAGE-VERSION/lib
```

and also creates links to those in

```
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
```

So, your `gcc` command will be:

```
g++-8 -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -lfmt <PROGRAM.CPP> -o <PROGRAM>
```

---

You can see what files belong to your `fmt` package and where they are with:

```
brew ls fmt --verbose
```

---

If you install `pkg-config`, using:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

it will use the file `fmt.pc` and can tell you the correct switches for compiling if you type:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags fmt
```

**Sample Output**

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/fmt/5.3.0/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/fmt/5.3.0/lib -lfmt
```

That means you can simplify your `gcc` command to:

```
g++-8 $(pkg-config --libs --cflags fmt) <PROGRAM.CPP> -o <PROGRAM>
```